# Parse-server: Reset Password

Tags: parse-server

I am trying to implement my own local parse-server with my application. Everything is working fine except for reseting password for users.

I receive the following error

```
(node:8729) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandledpromiserejection 
(rejection id: 2): Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL was not found on 
the server.</p>
<p>If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? i'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the email adapter configured in index.js? As per documentation,

> Email verification and password reset
>
> > Verifying user email addresses and enabling password reset via email requires an email adapter. As part of the parse-server package we provide an adapter for sending email through Mailgun. To use it, sign up for Mailgun, and add this to your initialization code:

```
var server = ParseServer({
    ...otherOptions,

    // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
    appName: 'Parse App',

    // The email adapter
    emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
        options: {
            // The address that your emails come from
            fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
            // Your domain from mailgun.com
            domain: 'example.com',
            // Your API key from mailgun.com
            apiKey: 'key-mykey',
        }
    },

    ...otherOptions
});
```